# Python equivalent to signTypedData for MetaTransactions?

Tags: python, meta-transactions, eip712

I have the following code in Node.js:

```
const dataToSign = {
  types: {
    EIP712Domain: domainType,
    MetaTransaction: metaTransactionType,
  },
  domain: domainData,
  primaryType: "MetaTransaction",
  message: message,
};

const signature = sigUtil.signTypedData(Buffer.from(private_key.slice(2), "hex"), {
  data: dataToSign,
});

let r = signature.slice(0, 66);
let s = "0x".concat(signature.slice(66, 130));
let v = "0x".concat(signature.slice(130, 132));
```

I would like to do the same in Python to sign a MetaTransaction but for some reason I don't get the same output:

```
data_to_sign = {
    'types': {
        'EIP712Domain': domainType,
        'MetaTransaction': metaTransactionType,
    },
    'domain': domain_data,
    'primaryType': "MetaTransaction",
    'message': message,
}

data = encode_structured_data(data_to_sign)
owner = Account.from_key(private_key)
signature = owner.sign_message(data)
```

Is there any equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by doing this:

```
    struct = EIP712Struct.from_message(data_to_sign)
    signable_bytes = struct.message.signable_bytes(struct.domain)
    keccak_hash = lambda x: sha3.keccak_256(x).digest()
    pk = PrivateKey.from_hex(private_key)
    signature = pk.sign_recoverable(signable_bytes, hasher=keccak_hash)
    v = signature[64] + 27
    r = to_32byte_hex(signature[0:32])
    s = to_32byte_hex(signature[32:64])
```